# set number entered by user and save it in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to save 10 numbers entered by a user into an array using a `for` loop. After that, I have to use an enhanced `for` loop to find the largest and smallest values in the array. I don't know how to save numbers in an array. I also have problems finding the smallest and largest values from the array and displaying them. I got an error on the `for` loop section where I set `highestvalue` and `lowestvalue=inputnumber`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //create a scanner object
        Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
        //declare largestNumber
        int largestNumber;
        //declare smallestNumber
        int smallestNumber;
        //declare inputNumber
        int inputNumber = 0;
        //declare array named number and set it to 10
        int[] number = new int[10];

        //display message
        System.out.print ("Enter an integer: ");
        //column headings

        for (int counter = 0; counter < number.length; counter++)
        {
            //set number equal to next input
            inputNumber = input.nextInt();

            number[inputNumber] = inputNumber;

            //for (number[inputNumber]>=largestNumber && number[inputNumber]>=smallestNumber)
            //{
            //largestNumber=inputNumber;
            //smallestNumber=inputNumber;
            //}
        }
        System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", "index", "value"); 
        System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", counter, number[inputNumber]);
        System.out.printf("The largest value in the array is %d\nThe smallest value in the array is %d\n", largestNumber, smallestNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
number[inputNumber] = inputNumber;
```

to

```
number[counter] = inputNumber;
```

You want to add each new number to the `counter` position of the array.

As for finding the minimum, maximum. The same loop that reads the inputs into the array can do that. Initialize `largestNumber` to Integer.MIN_VALUE and `smallestNumber` to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Then, each time you get a new number, compare it to both `largestNumber` and `smallestNumber`, and update them if the new number is higher/lower respectively.

Comment: i got the error for my for statement "for (number[inputNumber]>=largestNumber && number[inputNumber]>=smallestNumber)". is there anyway to rewrite this or i have to make 2 separate for statement

Comment: @andylie You should either use `number[counter]` or `inputNumber` (they should be the same), not `number[inputNumber]`.

Comment: @andylie And you don't need an additional for loop.

Comment: okay, when i enter my number, somehow i always get error if i enter a number greater or equal to 10. this is the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at ArrayTester.main(ArrayTester.java:36)"

Comment: @andy Of course you do, since you are using the input number as an index of your array, and the valid indices are 0 to 9. Make the changes I suggested and it won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`number[inputNumber] = inputNumber;`

with

`number[counter] = inputNumber;`

and thats it. As for finding mix and max, use `Collections.sort()` on your array. First element will be min, and the last max.

Comment: Collections.sort() is applicable to classes that implement List interface.Use Arrays.sort() instead

Answer (score 0):

```
make the following changes


        //create a scanner object
        Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
        //declare largestNumber
        int largestNumber;
        //declare smallestNumber
        int smallestNumber ;
        //declare inputNumber
        int inputNumber = 0;
        //declare array named number and set it to 10
        int[] number = new int[10];

        //display message
        System.out.print ("Enter an integer: ");
        //column headings

        for (int counter = 0; counter < number.length; counter++)  
        {
            //set number equal to next input   
            inputNumber = input.nextInt();
            number[counter] = inputNumber;

// for loop that will check for largest and smallest no



        }
         smallestNumber = number[0];
         largestNumber = number[0];

        for(int i=1; i< number.length; i++)
        {
                if(number[i] > largestNumber)
                    largestNumber = number[i];
                else if (number[i] < smallestNumber)
                        smallestNumber = number[i];

        }

      //  System.out.printf("%s%8s\n", "index", "value"); 
      //  System.out.printf("%5d%8d\n", counter, number[inputNumber]);
        System.out.printf("The largest value in the array is %d\nThe smallest value in the array is %d\n", largestNumber, smallestNumber);
```

Also: you cannot use a for loop in this way

```
for (number[inputNumber]>=largestNumber && number[inputNumber]>=smallestNumber)
```

this is a conditional case not a loop

Comment: okay, I don't know why but somehow I always get 0 as my smallestNumber. and i just follow your code format.

Comment: well, what I want is to find the largest number and smallest from user input and then saved in the array. somehow I always get the smallest number is zero (well, I know that we declare variable smallestNumber and set it equal to zero as default). but I don't want zero as my smallestNumber unless I did put in that number

Comment: i have sorted out it for you check the edit its what u want @andylie

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you don't have to store the numbers in the same order in which they were entered by the user, you would make a sorted insert. that means, for each value entered, find the index at which this number can be inserted while maintaining a sorted array (if there exists a number at this index you have to move it move it to the *right*)

provided a sorted array you can find min and max in O(1):
min = number[0];
max = number[n-1];

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try out this one.Let me know if it works.:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int num[]=new int[10];
int max=0,min=0;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   System.out.println("Enter number:-");
   num[i]=in.nextInt();

   if(num[i]>=max)
   max=num[i];
   if(num[i]<=min)
   min=num[i];
}
min=num[0];
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(num[i]<=min)
    min=num[i];
}
System.out.println("The array elements are:-");
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
System.out.print(num[i]+"  ");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Largest is:-"+max+" "+"Smallest is:"+min);
}
}
```